# Where should I add logging in my Go web scraper?

Tags: logging, go

I'm writing a suite of website scraper functions. Each function reads an HTML document and returns a single value. To tie this all together, I've got a function - let's call it `ScrapeUrl` that accepts and reads a URL, then builds a struct instance out of the results from each of the scraper functions in the suite.

I want to add logging to this so that I can see when non-critical values from the scraper functions are missing. But I don't know where the logger would slide in - should I log from:

1. Inside each scraper function?
2. Inside the `ScrapeUrl` function, based on the return value?

I have a feeling it's #2 but I'm not familiar w/ global loggers like what Go offers. Instead, I'm used to named loggers.

Thanks

Comment: Why not to have both? Where to add the log is very subjective and depends basically is to assure that the program is working and have hints on where to start debugging when it does not. So free to do what is the best in this particular case and then constantly improve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a named logger such as github.com/golang/glog to log both, but only output what you want when you need it.